# how to add times to loop everytime the method runs?

Tags: java, for-loop

I need to have a loop that loops X times that after X times stops and adds 5 times to loop. How can I do that and what am I doing wrong?

```
private void loopMethod(anClass someName) {
    int g = 0;
    Random o = new Random();
    int l = 50;
    int a = l + g;
    //System.out.println(g);
    for (int k = 0; k < a; k++) {
        int p = o.nextInt(100);
        if(a == 100){
            k = 101;
        }
        if (p == 1) {
            k = 101;
        } else {

        }
    }
    g = g + 5;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with add 5 times to loop? Do you mean the amount of loops? Then you shouldn't declare g as a local variable (since it will be resetted everytime you run the method) but as a class field.

Comment: i want to loop 50 times to start with, after the loops are done i want to add 5 tot the amount of loops it needs to do the next time the method runs.

Comment: Start by declaring `g` as global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by declaring `g` as Global Variable. You can do this as follows:

```
/* Global Declarations */
private Random o = new Random();
private int g = 0;

/* Logic */
private void loopMethod(anClass someName) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 50 + g; k++) {
        if(g == 50 || o.nextInt(100) == 1)
            k = 101;
        else
            /* Do Something */
    }
    g += 5;
}
```

This should fulfill your needs.

Comment: ok done that but g is 0 everytime i run the method i need to have g to add 5 everytime the method runs. also changed

'code'
        if(a == 100){
k = 101;
g = 0;}

Comment: no i was being dumb and run the application twice instead of running the method twice in the application. thank you for helping

Comment: Your Welcome. Sometimes it happens with me also. :)